Unable to retrieve session value in Go Gin
Problem: The session data set during login is not persisting across subsequent requests.
Expected output: The session data set during login should be stored and is accessible persist requests.
func (app *application) loginPostRequest(c *gin.Context) {

    // Response struct
    type User struct {
        Email    string `json:"email"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
    }

    var userData User

    // Bind the JSON data from the request to the userData struct
    if err := c.BindJSON(&userData); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": "Invalid JSON",
        })
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(encrypt(userData.Password))

    err := app.database.loginUser(userData.Email, userData.Password)

    if err != nil {
        if err.Error() == "user does not exist" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error": "User does not exist",
            })
            return
        }
        // For other errors during login, return a generic error response
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": "Invalid email or password",
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": "User logged in successfully",
    })

    // Get user id from the database
    userID, err := app.database.userId(userData.Email)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "error": "Failed to get user id",
        })
        return
    }

    session := sessions.Default(c)
    session.Set("userInfo", userInfoStruct{UserId: userID, Email: userData.Email})

    //fmt.Println("Session value: " + session.Get("userInfo").(userInfoStruct).Email)
    fmt.Println("Session object inside loginPostRequest: ", session)
    if err := session.Save(); err != nil {
        app.errorLog.Printf("Failed to save session: %v", err)
    }

    session = sessions.Default(c)
    fmt.Println("Session object inside loginPostRequest2: ", session)
}


Main.go code snippet:
import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/gob"
    "flag"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/cookie"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func init() {
    gob.Register(userInfoStruct{})
}

func main() {
router := gin.Default()

    store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
    store.Options(sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",           // Available across the entire domain
        Domain:   "", // Adjust to your domain, use an empty string for localhost or omit for default behavior
        MaxAge:   3600,          // Expires in 1 hour
        Secure:   false,         // Set to true if serving over HTTPS, false otherwise
        HttpOnly: true,          // Recommended: JavaScript can't access the cookie
    })
    router.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))

    router.LoadHTMLGlob("ui/html/**/*")
    router.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("./ui/static"))
    router.StaticFS("/userUploadDatas", http.Dir("./userUploadDatas"))
    router.StaticFS("/internalImages", http.Dir("./internal"))
    router.StaticFS("/favicon.ico", http.Dir("./internal/favicon.ico"))

    // Set up the routes.
    app.routes(router)

    // Start the HTTP server.
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:     *addr,
        ErrorLog: errorLog,
        Handler:  router,
    }
    infoLog.Printf("Starting server on localhost%s", *addr)
    err = srv.ListenAndServe()
    errorLog.Fatal(err)
}

Terminal Output:
Session object inside loginPostRequest:  &{mysession 0xc0001ba500 0xc00006a000 0xc00041adc0 true 0xc00051a100}
Session object inside loginPostRequest2:  &{mysession 0xc0001ba500 0xc00006a000 0xc00041adc0 false 0xc00051a100}

I tried a lot but is unable to fix this problem. If anyone helps then that would be great.
I have re-initialized the session in the same function so that I don't have to upload code of other functions and it will be easier to understand the problem. I won't be re-initializing the session twice otherwise just incase it bothers you.

Calling c.JSON(http.StatusOK... will send a response. This means that a later call to session.Save() will attempt to add a cookie to a response that has already been sent (the same applies to the errors you may attempt to send after sending the OK). To fix this move the http.StatusOK call to the bottom of the function. Note that session.Save() does not update the session in the current context so the loginPostRequest2 output is to be expected.
